# Reason for result of output of Python code

Tags: python-3.x

why the while loop is executing more times than expected in printing a pascal triangle?
every time the while loop is executed x is incremented by 1 whereas n remains the same
I just started learning python
please help

```
memo = {0:1}
def fac(n):
    if n not in memo:
        memo[n] = n*fac(n-1)
        return memo[n]
    else:
        return memo[n]

def pascal(x, space):
    while(x <= n):
        for j in range(space):
            print(" ", end = "")
        for i in range(0, x+1):
            print ( int(fac(x)/(fac(i)*fac(x-i))), end = " " )
        print("\n", end = "")
        x += 1
        space -= 1
        pascal(x, space)

n = eval(input())
space = n
x = 0
pascal(x, space)
```

Comment: what memo has to do with it?
Function of memo is just to calculate factorial and store it respectively in a dictionary @AzatIbrakov

Comment: What exactly is "more times than expected"?

Comment: @gabrielbelini please run it and see

Comment: you probably should use [factorial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.factorial)

Comment: whats wrong in using memo?
just applying dynamic programming @AzatIbrakov

Comment: btw @AzatIbrakov I checked it, using your way, gives the same output

Comment: i know, but reinventing the wheel is not good

Comment: remove inner recursive call `pascal(x, space)` and it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two methods to iterate through the numbers in the `pascal` function, a `while` loop, and a recursive call.  You just need one of them.

Keeping the `while` loop:

```
def pascal(x, space):
    while(x <= n):
        for j in range(space):
            print(" ", end = "")
        for i in range(0, x+1):
            print ( int(fac(x)/(fac(i)*fac(x-i))), end = " " )
        print("\n", end = "")
        x += 1
        space -= 1
```

Keeping the recursive call, turning the `while` into an `if`:

```
def pascal(x, space):
    if(x <= n):
        for j in range(space):
            print(" ", end = "")
        for i in range(0, x+1):
            print ( int(fac(x)/(fac(i)*fac(x-i))), end = " " )
        print("\n", end = "")
        x += 1
        space -= 1
        pascal(x, space)
```

Given 3 as input, both versions print the following:

```
   1
  1 1
 1 2 1
1 3 3 1
```